# Display the image using Eval function in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, eval

I would like to display the image which i have stored as `byte` in Sql Table.

ItemTemplate code

```
ImageUrl=<%# Eval("Image")%>
```

Image is the byte from `sql server`. In my application couldn't able to show the picture from server.

SQL Schema : `[Image]` `[image]` `NULL`

Please suggest, how to display the image.

Comment: did you tried searching on google for this ??

Answer (score 0):

As if you have tried, you might have got some useful links. However here you go.

**STEPS:-**

1.To retreive Images from database, first you change your `datatype` from `Image` to `nvarchar(550)`

2.You need to write code fetching images on the basis of **ID**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["ImageID"] != null)
    {
        string strQuery = "select ImageName, ImagePath, ImageData from youtableName where id=@id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ImageID"]);
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        if (dt != null)
        {
            Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
            + dt.Rows[0]["ImageName"].ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

`GetData` will be your datatable value which will be coming from the database.

3. To Display the image on the aspx page I have used ASP.Net Image Control refer below.

```html
<asp:image id="Image1" runat="server" imageurl="ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=1" />
<asp:image id="Image2" runat="server" imageurl="ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=2" />
<asp:image id="Image3" runat="server" imageurl="ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=3" />
```

Here is your complete reference:-

[Display Images from the database using asp.net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Images-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx)